# B12 deficiency in vegans

Tags: veganism, health, b12, supplements

As far as we know, vegans need to supplement with B12 to prevent deficiency due to a higher risk of such.

How long does it take for B12 deficiency to develop, if a vegan person does not take any B12? If there is no access to supplementation, how long is it possible to live without any health risks like nerve damage etc.?

Comment: P.S. I understand it is hard to give an estimate, depends on many factors, but like inaccurate average values would be also ok.

Comment: Some recent blood tests were good for everything except low B12 but I have not had previous tests so I don't know when it developed.  I am now taking a supplement but it disappoints me that I need to; I prefer natural sources.

Comment: https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/vitamin-b12-or-folate-deficiency-anaemia/treatment/#targetText=If%20your%20vitamin%20B12%20deficiency,the%20rest%20of%20your%20life.&targetText=Cyanocobalamin%20injections%20are%20not%20routinely,hydroxocobalamin%20is%20the%20preferred%20treatment.

Comment: It says you need to inject B12 every 2~3 months basis.

Comment: Why is this question marked as "duplicate" without a link? Also, I think the Game Changers movie says that even non-vegans tend to be low on B12 and that if they are less deficient than vegans it's because the animals they eat have been fed B12 supplements. I thought that was interesting.